# Google App Engine on cyrillic

Tags: google-app-engine, encoding, character-encoding

How can I get cyrillic text in html-code on GAE?

I tried

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
```

and

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

in the head tag, but it didn't seem to work. I get the cyrillic signs on "monkey language" e.g.

Ñ„Ð´Ñ„
fÐ³Ð³Ñ„Ð³Ñ„Ð³Ð´ÑÐ²

My HTML-code is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <link href="./css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>Заглавие</title>
  </head>

  <body>  
   Здравей!
  </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There's not enough information here to answer your question well. What exactly have you tried, and what result did you see? Show as much of your HTML as is relevant.

Comment: How are you representing your Cyrillic text on your page? Post that HTML, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out!

The problem was that the document is JSP and not HTML file.

If someone wants cyrillic in jsp files one should add

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
```

at the beginning of the file.